# Embed gettext translation (po) data into binary

Tags: gtk, gettext, glib, gtkmm

Is there a way to embed the contents of po files and bind the text domain (~ `bindtextdomain(GETTEXT_PACKAGE,...)`) to that embedded data?

The background is that I'm building a GTK application with gtkmm and I'm embedding most of the resources inside the application as gresources. The aim is to make the application as portable as possible as this will not be something that is installed or packaged - so a single binary/executable file is ideal. Currently the translation po files are the only thing I'm not able to embed.

Note: I don't need a GTK/Glib/gresource specific solution.

Comment: You could extract the necessary file(s) in a temporary directory and use from there, but admittedly that is not very elegant.

Comment: That's actually close to what I'm doing - I'm dynamically downloading them if they're not where they should be - and it is indeed not elegant.